# How to send BACKSPACE in expect?

Tags: linux, expect

I'm trying to automatize some tool, and I  have

```
 spawn  /home/rundoc.sh $path $view
 expect "Please enter correct product number []"
 sleep 2
 send "CX102504\r"
```

Problem is that by default in prompt is added last product number , for example

```
Please enter correct product number [] CX000001
```

When I run my expect script in prom is added

```
Please enter correct product number [] CX000001CX102504
```

So how I can tell in except that send BACKSPACE (delete) default product number add set only new one in prompt 
for example , something like

```
send "<BACKSPACE><BACKSPACE><BACKSPACE><BACKSPACE><BACKSPACE>CX102504\r"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternately you could use `\025` once -- that is Ctrl-U which (for readline editing) removes everything between the cursor and the start of the line.

Answer (score 5):

```
send \010
```

This will send backspace character. It is basically the octal representation of the backspace character.

Reference : [ASCII Table](http://foldoc.org/ASCII+character+table) & [Tcl Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3038)

Comment: HI, BACKSPACE works, I tried delete too send "\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177$product_number\r"     , but I get  Please enter correct product number [CX0023586] ^O7777777777777777CX555566